# In SAP Logon, how to choose SAP system by VBA

Tags: vba, sap-gui

I've dug the whole Internet but haven't found something similar.

I am writing the VBA program which extract data from SAP software to Excel and everything goes well. I want automate the whole process and opening a SAP Logon by VBA that's not a problem, but in our company there are many systems based on SAP, so between opening the SAP Logon and the authorization there is a window where I should select a server (screenshot). Do you know how can I automate server choosing by VBA?

[image]
ty so much for attention.

Answer (score 1):

I use the code below to choose SAP system.

```
Sub Choose_SAP(system_SAP As String, userSAP As String, passwordSAP As String)                                                                    

     Dim APP As Variant                                             
     Dim SapGuiAuto As Variant                                      
     Dim Connection As Variant                                      
     Dim session As Variant                                            

     Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")

     Set APP = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine

     Set Connection = APP.OpenConnection(system_SAP , True)

     Set session = Connection.Children(0)

     session.FindById("wnd[0]").maximize
     session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-BNAME").Text = userSAP
     session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/pwdRSYST-BCODE").Text = passwordSAP
     session.FindById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
End Sub
```

I hope this works for you!